# twitter's api secret is longer than QuickBlox 40 characters twitter secret limit. How will they ever match?

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, quickblox

Ok I think that the question is pretty straightforward. My problem is that quickblox has a required field of twitter secret on your app settings if you want to use twitter login. It just accept up to 40 characters but my secret is longer than that and when I try to login to quickblox using my twitter token and app secret it gives me a "Bad authentication error". Its just on the quickblox part, since I have to first signin to twitter to get the token and everything runs fine.

[Here is a screenshot of the quickblox field with the limit prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWV4Q.png)

Comment: Where it accepts 40 characters? API or dashboard ?

Comment: dashboard, it have a max of 40 characters @IgorKhomenko